# how to make statistics links in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to catch customers info:

1- they come from which site (from)

2- they click on which ad (ad)

3- I want to make dynamic link with laravel but I don't have any Idea?
and after click on this link make a statistics record on a mysql table

I want to get such as this **link**:

> http://example.com/?from=othersite&ad=ppc&source=Fastclick or
>   http://example.com/othersite/ppc/Fastclick

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: So I'm new in Laravel & I don't have any idea.

Comment: Will the user always be sent to the homepage or could it be to any page on your site with the query string example?

Answer (score 0):

you can use request data to get that data. For example:

```
public function getUserData(Request $request)
```

then in the request, you will get all data from request then you can parse as you like and save it into the database like which returns you all params from the request into an associated array:

```
$request->all()
```